# Forwarding SQL traffic to another machine on LAN

Tags: networking, vpn, windows-networking

I have a desktop on my home LAN that is connected to my work network via VPN, which allows the desktop to access a SQL server on the work network. My goal is for my laptop, which has no VPN connection to my work network, to somehow be able to access the same SQL server through the desktop. Is this possible? Both the desktop and laptop are using Windows 10.

Edit: Note that the VPN on the desktop is achieved through MikroTik, which is not portable.

Comment: simplest solution by far is to use Remote Desktop to connect to the desktop from the laptop and just do the work on the desktop itself.

Comment: it sounds like your situation is based on a specific network topology. could you please add a network diagram to your question? it sounds like we cannot be successful without one.

Answer (score 0):

Easy workaround: use remote desktop from laptop to control PC with VPN

1. Can you not ask your work to setup the VPN on the laptop?
2. Can you possibly duplicate the desktop VPN settings yourself to the laptop?
3. You could possibly do internet connection sharing (designed to share one network adapter connected to internet to another network adapter). Probably won't work with a VPN though

I am sure your work may not like the idea of any of those since usually VPN's are deployed for security & your kind of working around it which may reduce security

Comment: The VPN on the desktop is achieved through Microtik, which is not portable.

Comment: I want to work on my laptop, so remote desktop is out of the question.

Comment: The ICS approach doesn't seem to work.

Comment: if the VPN is connected to the router, can you connect the laptop to that router? perhaps you could install a wifi access point connected to your VPN router, and connect to it from the laptop? Otherwise it sounds like the laptop and desktop are not on the same lan anyway, if the laptop cannot use the VPN on the router. is that the case?

Comment: @Nick please update your question indicating you do not want the desktop used at all, like through remote desktop. Also indicate how your physical network is setup & if possible the mikrotik model so we can guide you accordingly. Frank is making really good suggestions